# The quickest method to detect if two slightly manipulated images are of the same object?

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, detection

I have a set of images and I want to find out which images are of the same object. Here are the different scenarios on how the object may be different among the images:

- Images of the object may be rotated 90, 180, or 270 degrees
- The object may be in a different spot in the image, but always in full fiew
- The object may be flipped within the image, either horizontal or vertical

I started by using the histogram of the image and MSE but I am getting incorrect results as some of the objects have the same color distribution.

I am going for speed here as my initial data set is 1000 images and will grow as the algorithm gets more mature.  So my initial thought was numpy/scipy but I am rather lost here. I have no experience in this area. I have read through the other posts on SO but they seem rather narrow in their scope. Does anyone have any experience or thoughts on how I could approach this?

**Edit:**
I do not have access to load any modules that are not part of the Python installation that is loaded on the machine that is running the script. Anaconda was installed so there are quite a few modules at my disposal, but no OpenCV.

**Edit**

Attached example files and answer file.

[Example Files](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgTk8Pn9uIwRgYpu4SmyyP9fmQXaoA)

Comment: When you say same, do you mean exactly the same?  If for each image the rest of the picture was cropped out except for the object would the resulting image be identical to the others in all aspects?

Comment: Yes, technically the object is always exactly the same - barring rotation and flipping. All the objects have a white background so ignoring the background is actually easy.

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem, but given your description of the objects in the images, I think you may have reasonable success with a k-Nearest Neighbor (kNN) classifier

Comment: Can you share some sample images please?

Comment: My laptop has decided to not want to connect to wifi. I'll upload a set when I get home.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Examples have been uploaded and edited into the post.